# Not able to download Rar file from gmail which contains my php project

Tags: download, gmail, rar

I have an email almost 4 years ago, which has RAR file in attachments containing my php project file. I want to download that file. But, nowadays gmail doesn't allow to send or receive any RAR file. Can anybody help me how can I download that zip from from my email?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> after searching, i open my blocked gmail attachment with third party
>   program like thundermail or something else,and download my file simply